# Have nginx serve up all files in a certain directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I want to have nginx serve up all images in /public/system/articles/images in my Rails app. I've tried
    location /system {
      allow all;
    }

which when I put in my_site.com/public/system/picture.png returns the Rails 404 page (as opposed to the nginx 404 page, or the image which is what I'm really after).

This is my current conf file:

```
upstream varnish {
    server localhost:6081;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_site.com;

    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)\?[0-9]+?$ {
      expires max;
      break;
    }

  root /home/my_site/my_site/current/public;

  location /system {
    allow all;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-AI-App "my_site";
    proxy_pass http://varnish;
  }

  #root /home/my_site/my_site/current/public;

  location / {
    # all IP addresses are listed here:
      allow all;

    try_files $uri @app;
  }

}
```

Comment: It might be your regex that's at fault.  I just tried this.  `file = "/system/articles/images/bar.png"; file =~ /\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)\?[0-9]+?$/ => nil`

Comment: If I disable that location directive I get the same error.

Comment: But is that the directive that you want to use to get it to serve static images?  If so you will need to fix the regex rather than disable it.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I'm being as clear as mud! The directive to serve images in /system is `location /system { }`, a bit further down. AFAIK that should be used ahead of the regex according to the way nginx orders directives, no? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: Also if I have something that isn't captured by that regex, so /public/system/test_file.txt for instance, I still get the same problem.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Thanks for having a peek at this. Turns out it was a simple URL-based misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: aha yeah - should have spotted that :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems I didn't need to do anything to the nginx conf files.

When trying to access things under the `/public` directory you don't put `/public` in the URL you're calling.

So instead of `my_site.com/public/system/picture.png` I should have been putting in `my_site.com/system/picture.png`